# TFDGUIxWaitCursor in formless application

Tags: delphi, firedac

The error I become is:

> Object factory for class {3E9B315B-F456-4175-A864-B2573C4A2201} is missing. To register it, you can drop component [TFDGUIxWaitCursor] into your project

Well, I would like to do it if I did not have a VCL-less (not console) application ...

There is just a "script" in DPR file and that's it.

Following does not help:

```
wCur := TFDGUIxWaitCursor.Create(nil);
conn := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
try
  .....
  conn.Connected := True;
  conn.ExecSQL('blah blah blah');
  conn.Connected := False;
finally
  conn.Free();
  wCur.Free();
end;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to create `TFDGUIxWaitCursor` explicitly.

In your case it is enough to include `FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait` in `uses` clause of your project file. All the neccessary initializations and finalizations are performed in `initialization` and `finalization` sections of this unit.

The concept of a wait cursor is abstracted in FireDAC (with the interface `IFDGUIxWaitCursor`) to work within FireMonkey, VCL and console applications. Therefore there exists different implementation for each kind in different units. Depending on your app-type, you have to choose the appropriate implementation. The designer usually add the right one if you drop a FireDAC component onto a form, frame or datamodule.

- Console: FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait
- FMX: FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait
- VCL: FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait

Comment: There is also silent mode. No need to include any FireDAC.xxx.Wait unit. Before using FireDAC (initialization section) you must set `FDManager.SilentMode := True;`